# The table does not render as expected when using jQuery code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to use for loop in the `order_data` array with dictionaries to display each data in table format. However, if I try to append the html in the for loop, each of the data cannot be displayed into each of the table rows accordingly. May I ask any methods can append the array data into table rows instead of only showing texts?

[image: Table data not able to be shown as rows]

```js
var order_data = [{
    "name": "John Chan",
    "mobile": "98674532",
    "address": "12/F, 123 Argyle Street, Mong Kok",
    "order_num": 75843,
    "price": 35,
    "status": "pending",
    "ordered_food": [{
      "name": "Big Mac Set",
      "price": 35
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "Frederick Hui",
    "mobile": "97558465",
    "address": "12/F, 50 Kennedy Road, HK Island",
    "order_num": 75956,
    "price": 40,
    "status": "pending",
    "ordered_food": [{
      "name": "Double Cheeseburger",
      "price": 40
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "Joseph Lau",
    "mobile": "95875648",
    "address": "7/F, 123 Waterloo Road, Yau Ma Tei",
    "order_num": 76452,
    "price": 28,
    "status": "delivered",
    "ordered_food": [{
      "name": "McNugget Set 6",
      "price": 28,
      "quantity": 1
    }]
  }
]
$(document).ready(function() {

  order_title = "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>" +
    "<thead><tr>" +
    "<th>Order No.</th>" +
    "<th>Customer</th>" +
    "<th>Status</th>" +
    "</tr></thead><tbody>"
  $("#order_data").append(order_title);

  for (var i = 0; i < order_data.length; i++) {
    html = "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + order_data[i].order_num + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + order_data[i].name + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + order_data[i].status + "</td>" +
      "</tr>";
    $("#order_data").append(html);
  }
  $("#order_data").append("</tbody></table>");
})
```

```css
.section {
  margin-top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top d-flex">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" width="75" height="75">
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="menu_items" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu_items">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Breakfast</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="deluxe_meal.html">Deluxe Meals</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Desserts</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drinks</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="customer_orders.html">Orders</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="incoming_order.html">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Locations</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Recruitment</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container section">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;">Customer Orders</h2>
    <br><br>

    <div id="order_data">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You can not assemble a proper table, by appending only parts of it at a time. Concatenate all your HTML code into a string variable instead, and then append the whole thing to the document in one go.

Comment: To clarify, jQuery's `append()` method accepts elements, not HTML fragments. You _can_ build the table by parts, but only as complete elements.

Answer (score 0):

You're appending to `$('#order_data')` rather than to the table within that container. If you look at the rendered source code, this is the html being created:

```
<div id="order_data">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead><tr><th>Order No.</th><th>Customer</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <tr><td>75843</td><td>John Chan</td><td>pending</td></tr>
  <tr><td>75956</td><td>Frederick Hui</td><td>pending</td></tr>
  <tr><td>76452</td><td>Joseph Lau</td><td>delivered</td></tr></div>
```

So you could just hard code the table, then inside your for loop would be:

```
 $("#order_data table tbody").append(html);
```

That being said, its better practice to mutate the DOM sparingly. (i.e. not using `.append()` in a for loop) You can use a `.map().join()` to iterate over your orders and build a single block of html. Then update the DOM just once with the entire html for the generated table. Also, you may want to use [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html) rather than [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/), since if you're replacing the entire table `.append()` will have undesired results after the first run. (assuming this will be updated via ajax)

Last thought, be careful with the hyphens and underscores. They are different and `#order_data` != `#order-data`.

```js
var order_data = [{
    "name": "John Chan",
    "mobile": "98674532",
    "address": "12/F, 123 Argyle Street, Mong Kok",
    "order_num": 75843,
    "price": 35,
    "status": "pending",
    "ordered_food": [{
      "name": "Big Mac Set",
      "price": 35
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "Frederick Hui",
    "mobile": "97558465",
    "address": "12/F, 50 Kennedy Road, HK Island",
    "order_num": 75956,
    "price": 40,
    "status": "pending",
    "ordered_food": [{
      "name": "Double Cheeseburger",
      "price": 40
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "Joseph Lau",
    "mobile": "95875648",
    "address": "7/F, 123 Waterloo Road, Yau Ma Tei",
    "order_num": 76452,
    "price": 28,
    "status": "delivered",
    "ordered_food": [{
      "name": "McNugget Set 6",
      "price": 28,
      "quantity": 1
    }]
  }
]

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#order_data table tbody")
    .html(order_data.map(order => `
      <tr>
        <td>${order.order_num}</td>
        <td>${order.name}</td>
        <td>${order.status}</td>
      </tr>`).join(``));
});
```

```css
.section {
  margin-top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top d-flex">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" width="75" height="75">
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="menu_items" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu_items">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Breakfast</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="deluxe_meal.html">Deluxe Meals</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Desserts</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drinks</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="customer_orders.html">Orders</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="incoming_order.html">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Locations</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Recruitment</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container section">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;">Customer Orders</h2>
    <br><br>

    <div id="order_data">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Order No.</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```